# How to display an hidden div on an image with low opacity

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have an image. I want to display an div on the image with same width and same height of the image when I put the cursor on the image. Background of the div will be black included with opacity .6. AT first Below I included an code, but it is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
.under_menu{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .5;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.image:hover .under_menu{
  display: block;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.main_menu{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

</style>
  </head>`
  <body>
     <div class="main_menu">
       <img src="com22.jpg" class="image" width="400" height="400" alt="" />
       <div class="under_menu"></div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As we all benefit of knowing which answer solved a specific question, it would be great if you could accept an answer, if any, that solve your question, or let us know what is missing, so we can find one that does

Answer (score 2):

Give `top: 0; left: 0; pointer-events: none` to `.under_menu` and change `.image:hover .under_menu` to `.image:hover ~ .under_menu` and it will work fine.

The `~` is the sibling selector, which is needed, as `.under_menu` is not a child of the `.image`, and the `pointer-events: none` make it not flicker, as it takes away pointer events from the `.under_menu`.

This could be done using pseudo element as well, showed in my 2:nd sample.

```css
.under_menu{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .5;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.image:hover ~ .under_menu{
  display: block;
}
.main_menu{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_menu">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/city" class="image" width="300" height="300" alt="" />
  <div class="under_menu"></div>
</div>
```

2:nd sample (using pseudo element)

```css
.main_menu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.main_menu:hover::after {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .5;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_menu">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/city" class="image" width="300" height="300" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `.image:hover .under_menu` will never work because this is telling the CSS that one hover of `.image` its "child" `.under_menu` should do something but `.under_menu` is not a child its a sibling so you have to do `.image:hover + .under_menu`.

Or if you don't have any other elements inside you can do `.main_menu:hover .under_menu`.

https://jsfiddle.net/up4oswLm/